# Using Ms Access LEFT JOIN to get previous balances as arrears

Tags: ms-access

Am trying to use left join to get previous school term fee balances as fee arrears for the current term. I already have a query displaying current fee balances. Am using the SQL below, I know am on the right track, please help.

```
SELECT Q1.pYear, Q1.term, Q2.Feedue As Arrears
FROM qryfeebalances AS Q1 LEFT JOIN qryfeebalances AS Q2 ON Q1.pyear & Q1.Term>Q2.pyear & Q2.term
GROUP BY Q1.pYear, Q1.Term, Q1.Strstudentid, Q1.Class;
```

Comment: What happens when you execute that? See if this helps http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Comment: `&` is the concatenation operator. If you want to check for multiple condition, it's `AND`, not `&`

Comment: Thank you all let me try and look at yours june7

Comment: It might have been 2018Term2Spring FeeDue of 100 as of the end of that term, but now in 2019Term1Fall they paid it in Sept.  SO, any query in Oct will get the wrong value??

Comment: DonPablo, I dont get you of

Comment: Pablo I don't get you because the 'arrears' + 'current term amount' will form the current   term's total 'fee to be paid'

Comment: SELECT Q1.pYear, Q1.term, Q2.Feedue As Arrears
FROM qryfeebalances AS Q1 LEFT JOIN qryfeebalances AS Q2 ON Q1.pyear & Q1.Term>Q2.pyear & Q2.term
GROUP BY Q1.pYear, Q1.Term, Q1.Strstudentid, Q1.Class;

Answer (score 1):

I got it, thought I should post so that someone may use it later.

SELECT Q1.pYear, Q1.term, Sum([Q2.Feedue]) As Arrears
FROM qryfeebalances AS Q1 LEFT JOIN qryfeebalances AS Q2 ON Q1.pyear & Q1.Term>Q2.pyear & Q2.term And Q1.strstudentid=Q2.strstudentid
GROUP BY Q1.pYear, Q1.Term, Q1.Strstudentid, Q1.Class;